# Browserify - Mentioning a function from the same file

Tags: javascript, browserify

I Am using `browserify` to do my JavaScript and I am having hard time remembering how to do this.

```
var account = require('./account');

module.exports = {
        start: function() {
            console.log('Logging');    
            module.music(this, 'game-bg.mp3');
        },
        music: function(arg, soundfile) {
            console.log('Playing music...');
            if (arg.mp3) {
                if(arg.mp3.paused) arg.mp3.play();
                else arg.mp3.pause();
            } else {
                arg.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
                arg.mp3.play();
            }
        }
};
```

When I run that, I get `Uncaught TypeError: module.music is not a function` and it never starts playing the music.

What did I have to do to make it working? I tried looking up the topics but I cannot find one mentioning multiple functions.

Comment: That's not polymorphism.

Comment: Having realized that now... I realize the error in my mistake @Achrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to reference another function in an object (and you aren't making a class so no `this`), then it is clearer and easier to just assign what you want to export to a variable and later export that variable. Like this:

```
var account = require('./account');

var player = {
        start: function() {
            console.log('Logging');    
            player.music(this, 'game-bg.mp3');
        },
        music: function(arg, soundfile) {
            console.log('Playing music...');
            if (arg.mp3) {
                if(arg.mp3.paused) arg.mp3.play();
                else arg.mp3.pause();
            } else {
                arg.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
                arg.mp3.play();
            }
        }
};

module.exports = player;
```

Comment: Thank. Much appreciated. Do you recommend any learning guides for OOP JavaScript?

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure about OOP specifically but I recommend "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninjas".